# Where (or how) is the keep-alive setting in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, keep-alive

I want to `keep-alive` on each connection, but for only max 5 seconds.

How can I setup this in `web.config` file, which section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS Manager, set the Connection Timeout, or, if you want to edit the appropriate file yourself:

IIS6: `C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\MetaBase.xml`

IIS7: `C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\ApplicationHost.config`:

```
<system.applicationHost>
   <sites>
      <siteDefaults>
         <limits connectionTimeout="00:00:05" />
      </siteDefaults>
   </sites>
</system.applicationHost>
```

Caveat: I haven't tried changing this setting myself.

Comment: **@EricYin** I tried adding this in my ASP.NET Web Application solution's `web.config` (right after the `configSection`) but I get this error: `Unrecognized configuration section system.applicationHost.`